# scrolling vertically to a specific text part in a webview

Tags: android, webview, vertical-scrolling

I'm looking for a way to scroll a webview that a specific part of the contained text is shown.

Scrolling programmatically needs always an integer value of how far to scroll. Is there any possibility of retrieving the y-position of a specific text in that webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the editor of the html content, you could simply use anchors inside the html :

The text I want to scroll to

and then simply use webview.loadurl("mywebpage.html#firstpart")

Comment: thanks, that sounds good. Does is also works with webview.loadDataWithBaseURL ?

Comment: Sorry never tried but you could use loadDataWithBaseUrl to load your page, and then call again loadUrl("mywebpage.html#firstpart"). Provided that you've given the proper base url in the first call, the second one should simply take you to the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

WebView has the `findAll(String)` and `findNext()` methods. They're not well documented though, and they seem to have some issues pre-froyo.

[This thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2695) in particular may help you give it a try, though. These find methods call native code, so it's not something you could easily override, I don't think. There might be something you could do with Javascript, but that's certainly not something I'm familiar with.